# How to increase the max connections, streams and threads in Wildfly?

Tags: java, jboss, stream, connection, wildfly

I'm building a notification system which allows clients to connect to a web-server and then get notified by server side events. I currently use Wildfly 16.0 standalone (on Windows) as web-server. I got server side events working with the example code below.

```
@GET
@Path("register")
@Produces("text/event-stream")
public void subscribe(@Context SseEventSink sseEventSink,
                      @HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.LAST_EVENT_ID_HEADER)) {

    while (true) {

        OutboundSseEvent sseEvent = this.eventBuilder
                .data("some data")
                .reconnectDelay(3000)
                .build();
        CompletionStage<?> cs = sseEventSink.send(sseEvent);

        cs.whenComplete((x, y) -> {
            System.out.println("Completed " + x);
            if (y != null) y.printStackTrace();
        });


        Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);

    }
    sseEventSink.close();
}
```

This solution is working for up to 120 connected clients with minimal server load, after that no new connections can be established.

I use ApacheBench, Version 2.3 for testing.

```
    ab -A 123:123 -c 120 -n 120 http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

If i go higher than 120 concurrent connections no one else can connect. This seems to me, that there is an active connection or stream or thread limit in place. If one user disconnects, another than can connect. I tried to set max-connections on the http-listener in the standalone.xml. This had no effect. I than simply added a zero to every connection / thread / pool option i could find. Still, no change.

Where to look next?

Comment: What version of Windows?  Windows 10, for example, is not meant as a server O/S and will have a lower limit than a Windows server O/S.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are not facing a connection limit problem, but instead wildfly runs out of I/O threads. If you run an 8-core CPU, it would match your mentioned about 120 concurrent clients: from https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/18.0/subsystem/io/worker/index.html#attr-task-max-threads

> Specify the maximum number of threads for the worker task thread pool.If not set, default value used which is calculated by formula cpuCount * 16

Increase the value with jboss-cli.sh:

```
/subsystem=io/worker=default:write-attribute(name=task-max-threads, value=1024)
```

Or in standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:3.0">
    <worker name="default" task-max-threads="1024"/>
    <buffer-pool name="default"/>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: only answer in the entire internet that worked. Thank you @nowoe

Answer (score 0):

You can add `max-connections` connections attribute to `http-listner` tag. e.g.

```
<http-listener name="default" max-connections="1000" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
```

With this you will be able to increase the maximum number of connections.

Note: This actually limits connections, without the attribute the implication is "unlimited"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are running out of connections because your `subscribe` method never returns because of that `while (true) { ... }` loop.

The following works for me:

```
@Singleton
@Path("")
public class BroadcastService {

    @Context
    private Sse sse;

    private SseBroadcaster broadcaster;

    @PostConstruct
    void initialise() {
        this.broadcaster = sse.newBroadcaster();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void shutdown() {
        this.broadcaster.close();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("register")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public void subscribe(@Context SseEventSink sseEventSink) {
        this.broadcaster.register(sseEventSink);
    }

    @Schedule(second = "*/5", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void broadcastData() {
        OutboundSseEvent sseEvent = this.sse.newEventBuilder()
          .data("some data")
          .reconnectDelay(3000)
          .build();
        this.broadcaster.broadcast(sseEvent);
    }
}
```

I tested with:

```
ab -c 2000 -n 4000 http://127.0.0.1:8080/sse-demo/register
```

and was still able to:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/sse-demo/register


retry: 3000
data: some data

retry: 3000
data: some data
```